# HTML improvement detection of duplicate page titles on AMP

Tags: google-search-console, duplicate-content, amp

I integrated accelerated mobile pages (AMP) on my site and it seems OK but I did notice something on the HTML Improvement. It seems that some of my pages that have AMP are considered to have duplicate title tags.

I wonder if it is because I put in a `rel=canonical` containing the original link of the page? I can see it on both code of the original page and AMP page. What else could be the reason of the detection?

I don't see any errors on the AMP Section in the Search Console for the AMP pages.

Comment: Are both pages (AMP and your main webpage) pointing to each other via rel source? Google is pretty smart to handle duplicate page title for many of things example AMP, pagination, href lang webpages etc.

Comment: @Goyllo Not each other but with the main webpage only.

Comment: Your all webpages(not only main webpage) should be point to each other. All AMP webpages should point to corresponding normal webpages and all normal webpages should point to AMP webpages. [This article might be helpful](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery).

Comment: Yes google is less problematic with duplicate content on the same sites now  in terms of not penalizing you as much. I can actually see my website page ranking twice and it s similar just one page is slightly different because it has a block of content the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`rel=canonical` refers to the actual page which should be considered as the source of the page.
You do not have to worry about SEO even if you have a 100 pages and all of them have the same canonical link